# React useEffect does infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My useEffect is getting data from web api. I want to render all posts on home page and trigger again my useEffect when someone create new post. The problem is when I put dependancy on useEffect its start doing endless requests. When I pass empty array as dependancy , when someone create new post it doesnt render on home page until I refresh the page. I read a lot in internet about that problem but still I dont know how to do it. Thanks

```
function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

    fetch('https://localhost:44366/api/Posts/getAllPosts',
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt
        },
      })
      .then(r => r.json()).then(result => setPosts(result));
  }, [posts]);


  return (
    <div >
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <main className="App">
          {
            posts.map(post => (
              <Post keyToAppend={post.CreatedOn} username={post.User.FirstName} title={post.Title} content={post.Content} images={post.ImageUrls} avatarImage={post.User.MainImageUrl} />
            ))
          }
        </main>
      </Router>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Post component :

```
const Post = ({ keyToAppend, username, title, content, images, avatarImage }) => {
    return (
        <div className="post" key={keyToAppend}>
            <div className="post__header">
                <Avatar
                    className="post__avatar"
                    alt="avatar"
                    src={avatarImage}
                />
                <h3 className="username">{username}</h3>

            </div>
            <h1 className="title">{title}</h1>
            <p className="content">{content}</p>
            <p>
                {typeof images != "undefined" ? <ImageSlider slides={images} /> : ""}
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Post;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `posts` from the dependency array, so it's just `[]`. That will run the effect once, when the component loads.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const jwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

  fetch('https://localhost:44366/api/Posts/getAllPosts',
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt
      },
    })
    .then(r => r.json()).then(result => setPosts(result));
}, []);
// ^^−−−−− remove `posts` here
```

The reason it runs endlessly with your current code is that your effect callback changes the `posts` state member, which triggers the effect again (because `posts` is in the dependency array).
You only need to include things in the dependency array that you *read* in the effect callback. You never read `posts` in the effect callback.

---

Side note: That code is falling prey to the `fetch` API footgun I describe [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html). You need to check `r.ok` before calling `r.json` (and handle errors):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

    fetch("https://localhost:44366/api/Posts/getAllPosts", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + jwt
        },
    })
    .then(r => {
        if (!r.ok) { // <=================
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${r.status}`);
        }
        return r.json();
    })
    .then(result => setPosts(result))
    .catch(error => {
        // ...handle/report error here...
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: I understand everything you said except "You only need to include things in the dependency array that you read in the effect callback.". I need to include in dependancy array props that Post component recieves or ? Sorry, but still dont get it.

Comment: @koceww - Nothing in the callback uses `posts`, so you shouldn't list `posts` in the dependency array. More: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect